# $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x ^{\sin x} $ to determine.

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to 0}  \sin x ^{\sin x} $
Hi, 
Help me do it please. I am asking for any advices, helpful observations. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, note that the expresseion makes little sense for negative (but almost $0$) values of $x$

Comment: look at $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x$ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=\sin x^{\sin x}$

$\log y=\sin x \log{\sin x}$

$$\log y={\frac{\log {\sin x}}{\frac{1}{\sin x}}}$$

Now you can use l-hopital rule as as $x \to 0$, $log \sin x \to -\infty $ also $\frac{1}{\sin x} \to \infty$

Can you do it now?

Comment: you r welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin (x)^{\sin (x)}=e^{\sin (x)\ln(\sin(x))}$$

Moreover $\sin x\sim x$ if $x\to 0$, therefore
$$e^{\sin(x)\ln(\sin x)}\sim e^{x\ln x}.$$

But $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=0$ and thus

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\ln x}=e^0=1.$$

Notice: your function is not define on $0^-$.

Comment: Why $x \ln x  \to 0 $

Comment: $$x\ln x=\frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}.$$ By l'hopital, $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(-x)=0.$$ But there is many way to prove it...

Answer (score 0):

We have $\sin x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, hence you may consider $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x$ instead.